# Java private/public encrypt exception data must not be greater than 256 bytes

Tags: java, public-key-encryption

I have this code below for encrypting objects, which does a job.
But I have an object containing a list of another object. When I encrypt the object I have the error that data must be greater than 256 bytes. When I remove the list, the encryption is managed without error.

```
public class A {
     private List<B> b = new ArrayList<>(); 
    //getter setter

}


try {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException
           | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RSA is not suitable for encrypting more than limited amounts of data. The conventional solution is [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) where the data is encrypted with a symmetric cipher with a nonce key and RSA is used to encrypt (only) the key. See for examples PKCS7/CMS/SMIME, PGP, XMLenc, JWE, SSL/TLS, and SSH.

Dupes here and cross-Stack:
[Encrypting large files using a public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491481/encrypting-large-files-using-a-public-key)
[How to encrypt a large file in openssl using public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143514/how-to-encrypt-a-large-file-in-openssl-using-public-key)
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-can-i-use-asymmetric-encryption-such-as-rsa-to-encrypt-an-arbitrary-length
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/why-is-padding-used-for-rsa-encryption-given-that-it-is-not-a-block-cipher
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/why-is-asymmetric-cryptography-bad-for-huge-data
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10685/hybrid-encryption-with-rsa-and-aes-versus-spliting-into-multiple-rsa-messages
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25899/using-ecb-as-rsa-encryption-mode-when-encrypted-messages-are-unique
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/why-does-pgp-use-symmetric-encryption-and-rsa